# Error running source run-gateway for Google IOT

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I have been trying to find help for this problem and there hasn't been too much success. I keep getting this error. I was following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi  and I haven't been able to get past step 14.

```
source run-gateway

Creating JWT using RS256 from private key file rsa_private.pem
on_publish, userdata None, mid 1
Unable to find key 1
connect status False
on_connect Connection Refused: not authorised.
on_disconnect 5: The connection was refused.
connect status False
connect status False
connect status False
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cloudiot_mqtt_gateway.py", line 356, in <module>
    main()
  File "./cloudiot_mqtt_gateway.py", line 284, in main
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully get the gateway running but had to manually modify the script. Make sure that you have updated the **run-gateway** shell script to point to your **registry ID** and **project ID**.

If any of the parameters are incorrect (e.g. device, project, region) then your device will be disconnected from the device bridge.